# Django returns 403 error on POST request with Fetch

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, fetch, csrf

I have a graphql server implemented using [graphene-django](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django). I can make queries to it using jquery like this:

```
function allIngredients() {
    return 'query{allProducts{edges{node{name}}}}'
  }
  var query = allIngredients();
  $.ajaxSetup({
    data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
  });
  $.post("/graphql", {query: query}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
```

However, when I try this call with Fetch, I get a 403, because of the CORS issue. I solved the same problem in jQuery by adding ajaxSetup... before the call.

Here's the call using fetch:

```
fetch('/graphql', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
          query:`{allProducts{
            edges{
              node{
                id
                name
                orderPrice
                sellPrice
              }
            }
          }`})
      }
    )
    .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
            throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
    })
```

I tried adding csrfmiddlewaretoken to the body in the similar way as I did in jQuery example, no luck. I tried adding credentials: 'include' as [the docs say](https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies), again no luck. I tried with credentials: 'same-origin' and combining this options differently, again the same result. Web is unusually quiet about this, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution was in the getCookie() method.

```
  fetch("/graphql", {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
          "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
          "Accept": "application/json",
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(query)
      })
```

And of course the method has to be on the same page. Taken from [Django Docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#ajax)

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you very much. I even had that getCookie() function available, I just wasn't passing it through the fetch header. Duh.

Comment: I had to do a hard reload, otherwise my js code didn't update. Same with css. I think it's because of the static files, you need to do hard reload to update it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make that post request form a different domain (in case when the front of the application is in React or angular and the backend is in Django), make sure the add following in the settings file:

1. Update the INSTALLED_APPS to use 'coreHeaders' :

   **INSTALLED_APPS = [

           'corsheaders',

        ]**
2. White list your front end domain by adding following to settings file again:

   **CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
   'localhost:8080',
   )**

Now allow the permission to make this post request for anyone:

**Note: Should be used in the cases where you don't need to authenticate the users for posting anything on our server, say, when a new user registers for the first time**.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

class CreateUser(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        return(Response("hi"))
```