# Django server reporting "Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)" despite sending token correctly?

Tags: javascript, django, csrf

I am trying to send a JSON POST request to my Django server.

It reports this error: `Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.):`

In my Django template, `options.html`, I say this:

`<script>const incomingToken = "{{ csrf_token }}";</script>`

And this:

`<input type="hidden" name="csrf-token" id="csrf-token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />`

Then in my JavaScript file that runs in the client I say:

```js
        const serverUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
        const headers = new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            // 'X-CSRFToken': getCookie("CSRF-TOKEN")
            "X-CSRFToken": document.getElementById("csrf-token").value
        })
        fetch(serverUrl, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                headers
            },
            mode: "same-origin",
            body: JSON.stringify(editorState.expirationDate, editorState.contracts, editorState.theta) // FIXME: server goes "Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)" and 403's
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(incomingToken)
            console.log(document.getElementById("csrf-token").value)
            console.log(response)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
```

Both `incomingToken` and `document.getElementById("csrf-token").value` report the same value. So I know I'm getting the correct string for the CSRF token.

How can this be? What am I doing wrong?

For reference, here is what I see in [another thread on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893537/fetch-set-cookies-and-csrf):

```js
const csrfToken = getCookie('CSRF-TOKEN');

const headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken // I substitute "csrfToken" with my code's "incomingToken" value
    });
    return this.fetcher(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers,
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: 'test@example.com',
            password: 'password'
        })
    });
```

Instead of running a function to retrieve the value from a cookie, I simply insert the value Django embeds using `{{ csrf_token }}`. I also tried pasting the code from [the top answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43869303/django-returns-403-error-on-post-request-with-fetch/43943556#43943556), including `function getCookie(name)`. Nothing. Client still says `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 403 (Forbidden)`, server still cries with the same `Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)` error.

Suggestions please!

Update:

So I tried a function from [Django's CSRF protection docs page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/) that reads:

```js
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

For whatever reason, this function returns a different value when I run `getCookie("csrftoken")` -- a value that is different from that of what is embedded by `{{ csrf_token }}`. Dunno what to make of that. Neither one works when inserting it into `"X-CSRFToken"` in my headers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem.

The solution came when I ignored much of what I found on StackOverflow and instead opted just to use the Django docs.

I had my code written as it is in my OP -- see how it makes headers out of `new Headers()`? And how the `fetch` has `serverUrl` plugged in as the first argument?

Well, I changed it so that it reads like this:

```js
const serverUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
        const request = new Request(serverUrl, { headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': getCookie("csrftoken") } })
        fetch(request, {
            method: "POST",
            mode: "same-origin",
            body: JSON.stringify(editorState.expirationDate, editorState.contracts, editorState.theta)
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
```

And it worked!

The difference was using the `new Request()` object in the `fetch` argument.